# Can Xcode 4 installer (The one 3.5 gb file) be used for diffrent Mac machines (Lion)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

**I have a slow internet download speed here. My question is, my friends has already downloaded the new Xcode 4 for Mac Lion Upgrade. I am thinking to reuse it for my Mac Book Pro to install Xcode 4, so can I use the same bundle to install XCODE 4 on my Mac Machine too or Do I need to download XCode 4 dmg again from the store ( Which will take too much time )
I also have a paid developer account, let me know if it helps. 
Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it? - the worst that can happen is that it says no.

Yes - at least I've done it with 4.0.2 on several machines. This works because it doesn't bother checking the MAS receipt (because it's free).